# Barred indices equation

Tags: equations, indexing

How to make the below equations with bars being precisely above selected indices and not crossing other unbarred indices?

[image]

```
  \begin{equation}
        \frac{1}{\alpha'}\int_\Sigma d^2x[g_{\mu\nu}\partial\phi^\mu\bar{\partial}\phi^\nu + ig_{i\bar{j}}\eta^\bar{j}(D_z\rho^i_{\bar{z}} + D_\bar{z}\rho^i_z) + i\theta_i(D_\bar{z}\rho^i_z - D_z\rho^i_\bar{z}) + R_{i\bar{i}j\bar{j}}\rho^i_z\rho^j_\bar{z}\eta^\bar{i}\theta_kg^{k\bar{j}}]
    \end{equation}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As said before: please don't post just code fragments. Always make a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/3225#3225)

Comment: The code you post raises errors but doesn't produce the output you show. Anyway, you've discovered that omitting braces leads to errors: you've got a lot of things like `\eta^\bar{j}` which should be `\eta^{\bar{j}}`.

Answer (score 2):

Never disregard errors raised during the LaTeX run.

Subscripts and superscripts should always be braced. In some cases (a single letter or digit) the braces can be omitted, but

```
\eta^\bar{j}
```

is definitely a syntax error, because TeX will take just `\bar` as the superscript.

You should also split such a long expression and make the brackets a little more prominent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
\frac{1}{\alpha'}\int_{\Sigma} d^{2}x\,\bigl[
  g_{\mu\nu}\partial\phi^{\mu}\bar{\partial}\phi^{\nu}
  + ig_{i\bar{j}}\eta^{\bar{j}}(D_z\rho^{i}_{\bar{z}} + D_{\bar{z}}\rho^{i}_{z})
\\
  + i\theta_{i}(D_{\bar{z}}\rho^{i}_{z} - D_z\rho^{i}_{\bar{z}})
  + R_{i\bar{i}j\bar{j}}\rho^{i}_{z}\rho^{j}_{\bar{z}}\eta^{\bar{i}}\theta_kg^{k\bar{j}}
\bigr]
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]